# How to navigate from UIView to a UIView Controller using segues?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8.2

**Aim: To show the View Controller - 'Welcome Page' with the button "Continue Here" from the previous view controller - 'Login Page'.**

I have been making this IOS app on **swift 3** in **Xcode 8.2** that has a login page coded programmatically and would like to transit to another page called the Welcome page that has a button on the screen in Storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

I'm having problems in connecting a **view controller that has been coded programmatically to another view controller containing buttons** that have been dragged on the storyboard. I have read many articles and watched many tutorials on constructing a segue programmatically and using them. Have also researched in using protocols to solve my problem but for some reason, I'm having an error.

I have tried implementing segues and giving them an identifier and then presenting them but didn't work as well. About what I meant by trying is I have used different commands such as dismiss, present, show but it **did not view the button** present on the next view controller. Here is the function of view controller class - 'Login Page' that has to move to the next view controller after the if statement so that it can show the view controller - 'Login Page' with the button.

```
func handleLogin() {

    //Guard statements are useful for form validation
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text
        else{
            print("Form not valid")
            return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil{

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "Incorrect Credentials", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            print(error)
            return
        }
        //Need to do the code here that can display the next view controller with the button
    }
}
```

Kindly help, please.

Comment: First, I don't know what to make of your snapshot. You show three storyboard scenes, but I'm not sure what the relationship between them is. Do you want the button in the second to take you to the third (in lower left)? This is very unclear. Next time, please label the various scenes and tell us which is going to which. Second, you say "I have tried implementing segues and giving them an identifier and then presenting them but didn't work". Well, that's what I would have suggested, so without seeing what you tried there and with telling us what you mean by "didn't work", we can't help you.

Comment: @Rob So sorry about not making it clear enough to answer my problem. Well, I would like to connect the lower view controller named 'Login Page' to the view controller 'Welcome Page' that has the button 'Continue here'.

Answer (score 0):

To segue programmatically to a Storyboard view, you'll need to instantiate the next view controller then call `pushViewController` if using a `navigationController` or you can use `self.present()`. Here is an example using a navigationController.

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
    return controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Note that you should change the storyboard name `"Main"` to whatever your storyboard filename is. You should also change `"NextViewController"` to whatever your controller storyboard identifier is (see Storyboard ID in image below). Also make sure to set your custom class in the storyboard (see Custom Class in image below).

[image]

Comment: I have used your method but it's not working. I'm able to move to the next view controller but cant view the button "Continue here". I would like to connect from 'Login Page' to 'Welcome Page'. Is there any other solution by which I can show the button on the next view controller?